# What is the name of pool which keeps transactions in memory such as Bitcoin's mempool?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin, confirmations, txpool

Do Ethereum clients have a memory pool which keeps transactions like Bitcoin's mempool?
If so, what is the name for it in Ethereum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called the Transaction Pool, or TxPool in the code.

From [go-ethereum - tx_pool.go, lines 35 to 62](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go#L35-L62):

```
var (
    // Transaction Pool Errors
   ...
)

const (
    maxQueued = 64 // max limit of queued txs per address
)

...
// TxPool contains all currently known transactions. Transactions
// enter the pool when they are received from the network or submitted
// locally. They exit the pool when they are included in the blockchain.
//
// The pool separates processable transactions (which can be applied to the
// current state) and future transactions. Transactions move between those
// two states over time as they are received and processed.
type TxPool struct {
    quit         chan bool // Quiting channel
    ...
```

In the Go Ethereum client implementation `geth`, you can type the following command to display a count of transactions in your pool:

```
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 0,
  queued: 1
}
```

The **pending** result shows the number of transactions ready to be "executed" (included in the next mined block). The Ethereum transaction pool also has a **queue** to hold transactions that are not quite ready to process, e.g. when the transaction nonce is too high. See [What happens when a transaction nonce is too high?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/what-happens-when-a-transaction-nonce-is-too-high).

And for comparison, here is Bitcoin's [txmempool.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/txmempool.cpp).