# How to configure max txpool memory size

Tags: txpool

What is the default txpool memory size in geth? How can I change the txpool memory size?

According to [What is the max size of transactions can clients like geth keep in txpool?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/what-is-the-max-size-of-transactions-can-clients-like-geth-keep-in-txpool), "The number of transactions in the pending transaction pool is effectively limited by memory." I wonder what the default setting is and how to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Geth**

The default config values associated with the transaction pool can now be changed from Geth's CLI:

```
TRANSACTION POOL OPTIONS:
  --txpool.pricelimit value    Minimum gas price limit to enforce for acceptance into the pool (
default: 1)
  --txpool.pricebump value     Price bump percentage to replace an already existing transaction (default: 10)
  --txpool.accountslots value  Minimum number of executable transaction slots guaranteed per account (default: 16)
  --txpool.globalslots value   Maximum number of executable transaction slots for all accounts (default: 4096)
  --txpool.accountqueue value  Maximum number of non-executable transaction slots permitted per account (default: 64)
  --txpool.globalqueue value   Maximum number of non-executable transaction slots for all accounts (default: 1024)
  --txpool.lifetime value      Maximum amount of time non-executable transaction are queued (default: 3h0m0s)
```

While this doesn't allow you to limit exactly how much memory is used, increasing, for example, `accountslots` or `globalslots` will lead to an increase in used memory, and vice versa.

---

**Parity**

Similarly, Parity has the following CLI option:

```
 --tx-queue-size LIMIT          Maximum amount of transactions in the queue (waiting
                                 to be included in next block) (default: 1024).
```

Comment: can you give us an example of using "--txpool.globalqueue" and "--txpool.lifetime" ? I am trying to limit queued transactions waiting time but nothing works for me

Answer (score 3):

grepping around **geth's** code I found the following:

**core/tx_pool.go**

```
const (
    maxQueued = 64 // max limit of queued txs per address
)

type stateFn func() (*state.StateDB, error)

// TxPool contains all currently known transactions. Transactions
// enter the pool when they are received from the network or submitted
// locally. They exit the pool when they are included in the blockchain.
//
// The pool separates processable transactions (which can be applied to the
// current state) and future transactions. Transactions move between those
// two states over time as they are received and processed.
type TxPool struct {
    config       *ChainConfig
    currentState stateFn // The state function which will allow us to do some pre checks
    pendingState *state.ManagedState
    gasLimit     func() *big.Int // The current gas limit function callback
    minGasPrice  *big.Int
    eventMux     *event.TypeMux
    events       event.Subscription
    localTx      *txSet
    mu           sync.RWMutex
    pending      map[common.Hash]*types.Transaction // processable transactions
    queue        map[common.Address]map[common.Hash]*types.Transaction

    wg sync.WaitGroup // for shutdown sync

    homestead bool
}

func NewTxPool(config *ChainConfig, eventMux *event.TypeMux, currentStateFn stateFn, gasLimitFn func() *big.Int) *TxPool {
    pool := &TxPool{
        config:       config,
        pending:      make(map[common.Hash]*types.Transaction),
        queue:        make(map[common.Address]map[common.Hash]*types.Transaction),
        eventMux:     eventMux,
        currentState: currentStateFn,
        gasLimit:     gasLimitFn,
        minGasPrice:  new(big.Int),
        pendingState: nil,
        localTx:      newTxSet(),
        events:       eventMux.Subscribe(ChainHeadEvent{}, GasPriceChanged{}, RemovedTransactionEvent{}),
    }

    pool.wg.Add(1)
    go pool.eventLoop()

    return pool
}
```

You can change the number of max queued TXs per address.

Comment: I'd like to know how to change the memory size, not max queued txs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by memory size. geth like most applications will use as much memory as available to store transactions.