# What is the difference between a pending transaction and a queued transaction in the geth mempool?

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool

I see the following on the wiki but I dont understand the difference

pending: all processable transactions

queued: all non-processable transactions

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look at the answer in [What is the max size of transactions can clients like geth keep in txpool?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/what-is-the-max-size-of-transactions-can-clients-like-geth-keep-in-txpool)

> **What is the difference between a pending transaction and a queued
>   transaction?**
>
> Pending transactions are transactions that are ready to be processed
>   and included in the block.
>
> Queued transactions are transactions where the transaction nonce is
>   not in sequence. The transaction nonce is an incrementing number for
>   each transaction with the same From address.
>
> For example:
>
> Transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonce 0 has been included
>   in the blockchain. Transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonce 1
>   has been included in the blockchain. 10 transactions from account
>   0xaaaa...aaaa with nonces 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 as sent to
>   an Ethereum node. These are placed in the transaction queue as the
>   transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonce 2 has not been seen
>   by the Ethereum node. Once the transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa
>   with nonce 2 is added to the transaction pool, the 10 transactions
>   with nonces 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 and 12 will be moved from the
>   queue to the pending transaction pool and all 11 transactions are
>   ready to be processed and inserted into into the blockchain (provided
>   there is enough gas).

Comment: Hi Badr! Could you please tell me if queued transactions with too high nonce are propagated to other nodes? I want to understand what happens with tx when I create tx with too high nonce. It's saved in a local queue, but do other nodes get the information about this tx? I don't know, can I remove it from the queue before it's mined and be sure that it won't be mined later by some node that received this tx before I removed it. I use parity if it's important.

Comment: Future transactions (queued due to nonconsecutive nonces) are not propagated. See https://openethereum.github.io/Transactions-Queue.html#:~:text=Note%20that%20a,would%20be%20invalid.