# Bitcoin has a mempool? Does ethereum has a mempool?

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool

Wondering if you know that. I checked 
https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#1,24h
and it gives interesting stats for pending transactions and fees. But I have never heard of mempool in ethereum ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Ethereum has a mempool which consists of all pending transactions. You can check this on [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/txsPending). It should be noted that transactions in Ethereum can be very different: a simple Ethereum transfer costs 21000 gas units, while a large contract call can take over 7 million units. To create such mempool for Ethereum I think the sum of all pending transactions gas limits should be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum is having a txpool in which transactions are kept (see [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3840/16) for a nice discussion of limits), that have not been mined yet.

In geth, you can inspect that txpool via [`txpool`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#txpool) and if you just want to get the number of pending transactions you can do `txpool.status`.

On Etherscan you can view a [chart of historic txpool size](https://etherscan.io/chart/pendingtx) as well as [a list of pending transactions](https://etherscan.io/txsPending).