# what is the difference between non-executable transactions and executable transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

In geth doc I found this :

```
  --txpool.globalslots value          Maximum number of executable transaction slots for all accounts (default: 4096)
  --txpool.accountqueue value         Maximum number of non-executable transaction slots permitted per account (default: 64)
```

But I didn't understand the meaning of "executable transaction" and "non-executable transaction"

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/what-is-the-max-size-of-transactions-can-clients-like-geth-keep-in-txpool maybe this could help. I guess the non-executable mean pending transactions

Comment: Maybe someone can ask on https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum or Discord and post the answer here.  @MajdTL comment sounds correct and it would be good to confirm from a Geth developer.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @karalabe's [answer](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20242)

> Executable means the account has enough balance to cover the costs and
> the nonce is either the next one in line, or there is a sequence of
> valid transactions with nonces leading up to the current one.
>
> Non executable means there's either not enough balance, or there's a
> nonce gap in the transactions, making the current one unexecutable,
> even if the block is empty.