# Txpool contains pre or post smart contract execution state?

Tags: txpool

I am trying to learn more about txpool and at what state transactions in it are in the overall lifecycle of an Ethereum transaction.

If I have a transaction that is going to call a smart contract, the transaction will have data that will be passed to the contract. This may alter the final state of a SC transaction, like slippage on a swap for example.

I'm trying to understand at what point that final swap value is fixed. Is it when the transaction reaches the txpool, or when the smart contract byte code is executed.

Does this relate to pending and queued transactions in the txpool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically  the state changes are being calculated when your transaction is selected to be picked in a block. Let's say you calculate the state changes at block X and the best way to meet your calculations is your transaction to be 1st in the X + 1 block. You can achive this manipulation by twitching the gas price.

For the difference between  ququed and pending check this answer:
[What is the difference between a pending transaction and a queued transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3840/67398)

> ### What is the difference between a pending transaction and a queued
>
>
> transaction? Pending transactions are transactions that are ready to
> be processed and included in the block.
>
> Queued transactions are transactions where the transaction nonce is
> not in sequence. The transaction nonce is an incrementing number for
> each transaction with the same From address.
>
> For example:
>
> Transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonce 0 has been included
> in the blockchain. Transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonce 1
> has been included in the blockchain. 10 transactions from account
> 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonces 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 as sent to
> an Ethereum node. These are placed in the transaction queue as the
> transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonce 2 has not been seen
> by the Ethereum node. Once the transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa
> with nonce 2 is added to the transaction pool, the 10 transactions
> with nonces 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 and 12 will be moved from the
> queue to the pending transaction pool and all 11 transactions are
> ready to be processed and inserted into into the blockchain (provided
> there is enough gas).

Comment: So a pending transaction that is in the txpool, which may be calling functions of a smart contract, which will result in a value being set i.e. swap rate for a token. In the txpool this smart contract function has not yet run?

Comment: yes, it will run and affect the Ethereum state once it is included in block