# What are those multiple transactions in the transaction pool?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, pending-transactions, txpool

I am running geth. Via `txpool.content.pending` I am looking at the transactions that my node currently sees. It gives me a bunch of transactions by their transaction hash (I think), in the below example I think the transaction has is `0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8`. This transaction has two child objects and I would like to know what those are. I am talking about `214823` and `214824`. What are those indices and why are there two transaction objects under the same hash? `nonce`, `to` and `value` are different, hence I am wondering why those would show up under the same transaction hash.

```
0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8: {
    214823: [{
        blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        blockNumber: null,
        from: "0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8",
        gas: "0x15f90",
        gasPrice: "0x4a817c800",
        hash: "0xf600f6000087513137182f9aee222618bb813e17cd1c550e710bfe532fc6c353",
        input: "0x",
        nonce: "0x34727",
        to: "0xd3642cbc286df002d4bba68f4dcdc00d19ccd553",
        transactionIndex: null,
        value: "0xde1a377aa686c6c"
    }],
    214824: [{
        blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        blockNumber: null,
        from: "0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8",
        gas: "0x15f90",
        gasPrice: "0x4a817c800",
        hash: "0x588bdf42eaf5e049c3a098be2104a7c5c65495154a5cacdb0161db158716ef0d",
        input: "0x",
        nonce: "0x34728",
        to: "0x4fed6e010dcdc0bf50c0cbc98ed33f1991b172da",
        transactionIndex: null,
        value: "0xde79cc181013590"
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These transactions are from a mining pool. You can see the frequently mined blocks in [0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8](http://etherscan.io/address/0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8#mine).

What you saw in `txpool.content.pending` are just two pending transactions representing the transactions that the miner is paying to the miners in the pool. Here is the [transaction list](http://etherscan.io/address/0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8) for the same account.

This mining pool is run by [ethermine.org](http://ethermine.org). You can see this by browsing one of the blocks from the list above. For example, block [1756807](http://etherscan.io/block/1756807) has the `Extra Data` of `ethermine.org (US1) (Hex:0x65746865726d696e652e6f7267202855533129)`.

The two transactions are under the same hash because are from the same address. The hash that you are referring to is not the transaction hash, but the address.

Here's the difference in length between an account and a transaction hash:

Account: `0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8`

- 40 hex characters, 20 bytes

Tx hash: `0x1f86911381fcb732d2a41e5aff428f6aa7916e6fd87e39a19d023fe7c0afdb0b`

- 64 hex characters, 32 bytes

See [What happens when a transaction nonce is too high?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/what-happens-when-a-transaction-nonce-is-too-high) for more information about transaction nonces.

Comment: thanks, I did not realize that they are ordered by sender but this is of course obvious because the `from` has the same entry. just for clarification: the second index (214823, 214824) is the nonce in decimal representation.