# How is a filter ID generated?

Tags: filters

If I create a filter with the same parameters twice in a row, I get different filter IDs. Is the ID deterministic? If so, how is it generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter ID is an [integer](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/290e851f57f5d27a1d5f0f7ad784c836e017c337/eth/filters/filter_system.go#L47), and is [incremented](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/290e851f57f5d27a1d5f0f7ad784c836e017c337/eth/filters/filter_system.go#L107) for each newly created filter, regardless of the parameters it's created with.

See also the following previous thread: [What's the maximum number of filters geth can hold and what happens when this maximum is met?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8054/whats-the-maximum-number-of-filters-geth-can-hold-and-what-happens-when-this-ma/8111#8111)

Comment: very well versed answer on filters, thank you for that. Would you happen to notice what I am doing wrong with my filter code on this question?: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22954/mistake-when-using-web3-eth-filter-and-filter-get

Comment: Apologies for the late reply on this - did you solve the filter issue in the end?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply to your reply :P, no I didn't solve the issue, wrote different questions trying to debug it with different angles, but no solution yet. Would you happen to know what it might be?