# Are transactions with too high nonce propagated to other nodes from local pool by parity?

Tags: mining, parity, pending-transactions, nonce, txpool

I want to understand what happens with tx when I create tx with too high nonce. It's saved in a local queue, but do other nodes get the information about this tx? I don't know, can I remove tx from the queue before it's mined and be sure that it won't be mined later by some node that received that tx before I removed it.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/what-happens-when-a-transaction-nonce-is-too-high